# How can I change back button's text on appdelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have navigationController and I want to change nav back button text on appdelegate. so I want to change every uiviewController's back button's text on appdelegate. Is it possible?

I wrote the following code but it's not working.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController =  self.navigationController;


    self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"custom back text"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];  // didn't work


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ? do you see a button ?

Comment: @giorashc this code : self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"custom back text"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];

Comment: I understand that :) but what do you see on screen ? do you see the button ? does the app crashes etc... ?

Comment: I edited question . Can you look @giorashc

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the AppDelegate. You're AppDelegate should be minimal. Load the first view controller, present it, done. The AppDelegate should do NOTHING else. (Well, except the UIApplication delegate methods). Editing the view controller like this is the job of the view controller

Answer (score 8):

You need to understand the difference between the navigation bar (there is one, owned, managed and controlled by the navigation controller) and the navigation items (there are many, one per view controller in the navigation controllers stack, owned and controlled by the view controllers). So you can't change it from where you are trying.

Instead, change it in each view controller or subclass the navigation controller (or act as its delegate) so you can change each view controller as its added to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer that appeared while I was typing.

For example:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"custom back text"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];
```

But be careful. WIth this you're now responsible for handling the button action and this one here will do nothing.